# Identify out of tree modules?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I'm attempting to [upgrade and test kernel 3.12](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Problems_installing_the_upstream_kernel).

What is the most efficient way to identify out-of-tree modules that should be removed before testing?

There are a few mentioned (vitualbox, nvidia, fglrx, bcmwl), but is there a way to identify installed modules that are considered out-of-tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discovering that the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Problems_installing_the_upstream_kernel) I am using is referring to *external modules*, it was easier to find a solution by rtfm.

**Summary of external modules install paths**

- External modules are installed with `modules_install` at `/lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/extra/` by default.
- When installing external modules elsewhere, `INSTALL_MOD_PATH` is used to prefix the installation path, or `INSTALL_MOD_DIR` is used to create a new directory under the usual `/lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)` path.

See the bottom of this answer for more detailed explanation.

**Searching for external modules**

To narrow the search down to the above, I'm using `locate` to print paths containing `lib/module` and `xargs` to [filter the output](https://superuser.com/a/408073/226738) of paths that are not directories.

Lastly, `grep -v` is used to filter the output of a paths beginning with `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel`. This should still display paths that were prefixed using `INSTALL_MOD_PATH` during installation, for example `/frodo/lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/kernel/`.

This obviously won't print the path of modules that were somehow installed in a completely weird path. Here is the command:

`locate --null "*lib/modules/$(uname -r)*" | xargs -r0 sh -c 'for i do [ -d "$i" ] && printf "%s\n" "$i"; done' sh {} + | grep -v "^/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel\|^/lib/modules/$(uname -r)$\|^/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build$\|^/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/initrd$"`

This prunes the in-tree paths from the output, which for me was 4695 lines when using  only `locate "*lib/modules/$(uname -r)*"`. Now the output is much less and should only display known out-of-tree paths:

```
/frodo/lib/modules/3.12.3-031203-generic
/frodo/lib/modules/3.12.3-031203-generic/kernel
```

---

**Excerpts from documentation Building External Modules**

The details below are from [Building External Modules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt)

```
modules_install
    Install the external module(s). The default location is
    /lib/modules/<kernel_release>/extra/, but a prefix may
    be added with INSTALL_MOD_PATH (discussed in section 5).
```

---

```
=== 5. Module Installation

Modules which are included in the kernel are installed in the
directory:

    /lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/kernel/

And external modules are installed in:

    /lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/extra/

--- 5.1 INSTALL_MOD_PATH

    Above are the default directories but as always some level of
    customization is possible. A prefix can be added to the
    installation path using the variable INSTALL_MOD_PATH:

        $ make INSTALL_MOD_PATH=/frodo modules_install
        => Install dir: /frodo/lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/kernel/

    INSTALL_MOD_PATH may be set as an ordinary shell variable or,
    as shown above, can be specified on the command line when
    calling "make." This has effect when installing both in-tree
    and out-of-tree modules.

--- 5.2 INSTALL_MOD_DIR

    External modules are by default installed to a directory under
    /lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/extra/, but you may wish to
    locate modules for a specific functionality in a separate
    directory. For this purpose, use INSTALL_MOD_DIR to specify an
    alternative name to "extra."

        $ make INSTALL_MOD_DIR=gandalf -C $KDIR \
               M=$PWD modules_install
        => Install dir: /lib/modules/$(KERNELRELEASE)/gandalf/
```

Answer (score 3):

Kernel modules, whether in-tree or out-of-tree, are installed in directories specific to given kernel versions (`/lib/modules/$(uname -r)`), so you shouldn't need to clean up modules to upgrade to a new kernel: the new kernel simply won't consider the old modules.

Nevertheless, as far as I'm aware in-tree modules go in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel`, so anything in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)` outside of that is an out-of-tree module.

Comment: I was getting a "bad return status" error due to virtualbox. I guess that's one way to find out. Worked find after removing it.